# Class inheritance with template

Tags: c++, templates

I've started learning C++ templates, so I wrote something like the code below. I used a template to make a "generic inheritance". It works, but I haven't found many similar examples, which leads me to believe that this is not a recommendable implementation.

#### edited

Sorry about the simple example, I will to try to improve this, so I'm writing a linear/nonlinear(extended) Kalman filter, and I'm using templates to define whether the system is linear or nonlinear.

```cpp
// https://godbolt.org/z/WhdonxY9x
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Linear
{
    public:
        Linear(){};
        void init(){};
        void time_update(){};
};

class Nonlinear : public Linear
{
    public:
        Nonlinear(){};
        void loadEq(){};
        void applyLinearization(){};
};

template <class Model>
class Filter : public Model
{
    public:
        Filter(){};
        void measurement_update(){};
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<double> data{0.3, 0.2, 0.3};

//  for nonlinear system
    Filter<Nonlinear> nFilter;
    for (auto x : data)
    {
        nFilter.applyLinearization();
        nFilter.time_update();
        nFilter.measurement_update();
    }

//  for linear system
    Filter<Linear> lFilter;
    for (auto x : data)
    {
        lFilter.time_update();
        lFilter.measurement_update();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That depends on what you're doing. There are good uses of inheritance and bad uses. All you've shown in a constructor in `Filter()`, so we can't really advocate for or against your particular use case, since I imagine your real code has more than just a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Using templates for inheritance is still fine, but there's a point where I wouldn't recommend to do that, especially when it becomes overly complicated with multiple templates to inherit.

Also, as Silvio Mayolo said, it also depends heavily on what you're doing. But generally speaking, I wouldn't say it's frowned upon to add templates for inheritance in C++, at least in my opinion. However, that could maybe change if you could tell us what you're going to use it for exactly.